# linux использует только часть процессоров

Tags: linux, железо, cpu, multiprocessing

Имеется восьмипроцессорный сервер. Каждый процессор по 10 ядер, итого 80 физических ядер. ОС Oracle Linux Server release 6.7, ядро 3.8.13-98.2.1.el6uek.x86_64

Проблема в том, что ОС использует только два процессора из 8:

[image: htop output]

При этом lscpu, говорит что все ядра задействованы

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                160
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-159
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    10
Socket(s):             8
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 47
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               2393.990
BogoMIPS:              4787.90
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              30720K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-159
```

Пробовал запустить strees -c 80, количество задействованных ядер не изменилось, только выросла la.
Не знаю куда копать. Признателен за любую помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить 8 процесов, сильно грузящих процессор. Например, какие-нибудь вычисления в цикле, с доступом к случайным участкам памяти. Посмотрите, будут ли загружены все процессоры.

Comment: Попробуй `SETI@home`. Прога выжирает всё, что найдёт.

Comment: @VladD запустил фрагмент perl кода: `fork for 1 .. 5;
for (1 .. 10000) {
my $a = "xxxxx" x int rand 10_000_000;
my $b = ~$a;
my $c = reverse $b;`
Ситуация аналогична запуску утилиты stress - растет la, нагрузка не ложится на другие процессоры. [htop_stress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbYGe.jpg)

Comment: Тогда что-то не так в конфигурации системы. Ищите.

Comment: ядра можно ограничить в grub, где то такой строкой `kernel        /vmlinuz- ....  quiet splash maxcpus=1`. Второй вариант - так собрано ядро. В любом случае, лучше почитать вывод dmesg, там будет что то да написано.

Comment: @KoVadim эту версию проверил одной из первых, но такого параметра нет, также вручную ядра не оффлайнились, что видно из вывода lspci. Ядро из репов oracle linux, сомневаюсь, что оно собрано так "интересно". Dmesg, к сожалению, тоже не содержит какой-либо ругани по поводу cpu.

Comment: я бы все таки конфиг ядра открыл и посмотрел (он часто в boot бывает). Параметр вроде NR_CPUS называется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Было обновлено ядро ОС.
2. В биосе выставил вручную количество задействованных ядер на CPU (опция Enhanced Processor Core Disable (Intel Core Select)).

После загрузки в ОС все ядра стали использоваться, stress -c 160, соответственно, нагрузил их все. Доподлинно сказать, что именно помогло не могу.

Всем спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

В конфигурационном файле генерации ядра есть такой параметр:

```
Symbol: NR_CPUS [=4]                                                                            │   
  │ Type  : integer
  │ Range : [2 32]
  │ Prompt: Maximum number of CPUs (2-32)
  | Location:
  │     -> Kernel Features
```

Сколько реально процессоров видит ядро, можно узнать с помощью команды:

```
sudo lshw | grep cpu
```

Что бы выяснить, как именно было сгенерировано ядро, которое Вы используете, надо выполнить команду

```
zcat /proc/config.gz
```

Но она отработает только в том случае, если тот человек, который собирал ядро, разрешил это делать.

Есть ещё вариант. Если вы ставили операционку стандартным образом, с помощью репозитария, то при автоматическом обновлении ядра, в папку */boot* будут писаться файлы, имена которых начинаются с *config-* Это и есть, конфигурация ядра, которое используется на Вашей системе.